# angular conditional watch to call a debounced method or not is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, debouncing

I have the following angular watch to watch for a scoped variable, and I perform the following. I use debounce to bundle the request to the backend.

```
  var myWatch = $scope.$watch('myQuery', _.debounce(loadMyData, 1000),true);
```

When this myQuery returns undefined, I don't need this debounceand instead I need to execute the backend  call directly.

```
  var myWatch =  $scope.$watch('myQuery', function(oldquery,newquery){
      if(newquery){
        _.debounce(loadMyData(newquery), 2000,true);
      }else{
        loadMyData(newquery);
      }
  },true);
```

now the debounce doesn't properly bundle my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a new function in a variable and call it in the watch listener:

```
var debouncedLoadMyData = _.debounce(loadMyData, 1000, true),
    myWatch = $scope.$watch('myQuery', function (oldquery, newquery) {
        if (newquery) {
            debouncedLoadMyData(newquery);
        } else {
            loadMyData(newquery);
        }
    }, true)
;
```